# Filtering The Wordpress Search

Tags: php, wordpress, function, search

I need help with **search.php** on a theme i'm developing. **Search Results are picking up url's from anchor tags** in **the_content()**;

I see many tutorials / code examples on how to exclude certain pages or posts from search results, but no way to be more specific about what i'm filtering within the content area.

For example lets call this site;

**bestcars.com**

When I search for **cars**, as expected my Custom Post Types's to do with **CARS** are showing, but also I'm seeing the **CONTACT US** page show up and the **HOMEPAGE** too.

Thats because within the CONTACT US page there is a button going to **FIND US** and because the url contains the word;

best**cars**.com/find-us/

This is showing in the **CARS** **results**.

**Ideally I want to filter;**

- the words within the base url only (if thats the only place they
  appear),
- any meta data from images and alt text,
- any urls or titles within anchor tags.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Take a look at elasticsearch. There is a WordPress plugin for that called ElasticPress. The plugin indexes your pages and adds them to ElasticSearch. Before indexing you can use a filter for the post_content, in which you can deleted the links. So no links get into post content on the elasticsearch server and hence you won’t get results for those.

Comment: Else you will wind up checking every search result for being inside a hyperlink. And if all of them are, exclude the result. it seems like a hassle to me, but it is doable.